# Trouble determining L of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is the matrix:

$$\mathbf Α = \begin{bmatrix} 
3  & -6  & 6 & -3\\
6  & -10 & 8 & -3\\
-1 & -4  & 10& -3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I am supposed to find an LU factorization** of the matrix $\mathbf A$.

i.e $\mathbf A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ is equal to $\mathbf L(\mathbf U \mathbf x)=\mathbf b$ if I'm correct.

Here is my **U** (U is the upper triangle, I row reduced without scaling and note that pivots aren't supposed to be $1$):

$$\mathbf{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
3  & -6  & 6  & -3\\
0  &  2  & -4 &  3\\
0  &  0  &  0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now I must find **L**, I understand $\mathbf L$ must form the lower triangle, but strangely pivots must now be $1$?

I've been having trouble determining **L**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix $\mathbf L$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix in the form $\mathbf L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ l_{21} & 1 & 0 \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, where $l_{ij}$ are the multipliers. How are $l_{ij}$ defined?

In order to find the $\mathbf{U}$ matrix, we do row operations. For example, in order to find the second row of the $\mathbf{U}$ matrix we do something like: 
$$ \mathbf{U}_2 := R_2 - l_{21} R_1,\tag 1$$
 where $\mathbf{U}_k$ is the $k-$ row of matrix $\mathbf U$ and $R_k$ is the $k-$ row of matrix $A$. In a similar way, we have that: 
$$\mathbf{U}_3: = (R_3 - l_{31}R_1) - l_{32} \mathbf{U}_2.\tag 2$$
Also, it is obvious that $$\mathbf{U}_1 = R_1.\tag 3$$

Now, taking advantage of $(1),(2),(3)$ we can easily verify that $$\mathbf L \mathbf U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ l_{21} & 1 & 0 \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & 1 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf U_1 \\ \mathbf{U}_2 \\ \mathbf{U}_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} R_1 \\ R_2 \\ R_3 \end{bmatrix} = A.$$

Below is the desirable matrix $\mathbf L$.

> Matrix $\mathbf L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\2 & 1 & 0 \\ -1/3 & -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: w8, shouldnt L be a 3*4 matrix ? my original matrix is 3*4

Comment: You cannot multiply a $3\times 4\, (\text{ your suggested } \mathbf L)$ matrix by a $3\times 4\, (\mathbf U)$ matrix. My matrix $\mathbf L$ ($3 \times 3$) multiplied by the matrix $\mathbf U$ ($3\times 4$) yields a $(3\times \mathbf 3) \times (\mathbf 3\times 4) = 3\times 4$ matrix (matrix $A$).